# Change image in svg element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am trying to modify an existing SVG element in an HTML document.
I have the following:

```
<svg class="logo" viewBox="0 0 435 67"> <!-- IMAGE DIMENSIONS -->    
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#logo--someLogo"></use>
</svg>
```

I guess it has to be in that `xlink:href="#logo--someLogo"` but when I try to change it through the browser with a .svg file or .png like

```
$('.logo use').attr('xlink:href', "//someurl.com.png");
```

it doesnt show anything.

So Im wondering how I can change that `xlink:href` with another source.

Answer (score 0):

maybe there are native methods for those kind of document nodes, but this also will work(if there is only one use tag).

```
document.getElementsByTagName('use')[0].setAttribute('xlink:href', 'link_to_another_image')
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I figured out that the way *svg use* works is that in the DOM there is a *symbol* tag that matches that resource specified *xlink:href*. In that tag, there is a *path* element in which the resource path needs to be specified.

I used a jpeg to svg converter to get the path of the image, and it seems to work when replacing the path in the *symbol* element in the DOM.